# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution: out of gas

Tags: ico, binance, presale

On BSC Testnet I have deployed a token contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xE5bB5e6Cf65dBE0062d1EBa9e36e64F89e3f0638

And also a TokenSale contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xe6A01F088fE30e613D8449D6DA04196C90D5F255

Then I created a temporary DAPP with a swap function connected to my Tokesale contract. Here it is: http://kurt.bestcoinx.com/

The problem is that when I try to swap I get an error for example this transaction:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x85b079d4351b16f8733e5b03dd97e7a8a4dfdddaa8037f3ce0c6a2ea9f4f16f7

with the error
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution: out of gas

1. I have BNB in my Owner wallet
2. I have sent a sufficient amount of my token to the Token sale contract.
3. I have tried sending BNB to my Tokensale contract and it failed too.

I don't know what to do to get this to start working and I will appreciate it if anyone can check these issues out for me.

Thanks

Comment: token and tokenSale links are the same

Answer (score 0):

Your WFT token's transfer method uses 65,994 gas for a transfer. The  buyWithBNB method from the TokenSale contract uses it and not only it. The gas limit which you set is 50,000, that's why it's running out of gas. Try to set higher gas limit for buyWithBNB transaction.

Comment: Thank you V1bio. I have increased the gas limit to TokenSale from the Dapp as you can see from another instance of my TokenSale. See tx has below: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x7f4cf58f3b2ecc9321288f0f718982f176950f4aa27f48e8b2b209ab97032aef. Transaction still failed with the same result.

Comment: @UgochukwuOzoamaka how much gas the transaction uses at your local testnet?

Comment: How do I figure that out? I am deploying using remix. Please guide me a little bit more. Thanks

Comment: @UgochukwuOzoamaka after you deploy your contract, execute the function buyWithBNB. There should be transaction report, check the execution cost.